# How to transfer props in react v0.13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn react for my first javascript project and as a start creating a very simple code that adds two numbers entered in a text box. The result is re-rendered as a number is typed. This worked for me on react v0.11.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            payment: 0,
            payment2: 0
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        var total = parseInt(this.state.payment, 10) +
                    parseInt(this.state.payment2, 10);
        return (
            <div>
                <Payment {...this.props} valueLink={this.linkState('payment')}/><span>+</span>
                <Payment {...this.props} valueLink={this.linkState('payment2')}/><span>=</span>
                { total }
            </div>
        );
    }

});


var Payment = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return this.transferPropsTo(
            <input type="text" />
        );
    }

});

React.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

However, it seems like the **transferPropsTo()** function was removed in v0.13. How do I do the equivalent in the latest version.

Comment: This gist explains different ways of doing it in v0.13 https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/a6e220b7097eb3c79ab7

Comment: JSX Spread - from Facebook: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `{...this.props}` in the input tag:

```
 var Payment = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
     return (
       <input type="text" {...this.props} />
     );
   }
});
```

This uses the JSX [spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) feature.